# How should I sort one word using shell?

Tags: shell

I can use every language to realize it, but I want to use shell.

1. Use shell command or shell script.
2. For example, I have one word: `sport`.
3. I want to get another word: `oprst`.

Now I want to use shell to bring about it, how to do? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Use the following Shell Script:-

```
#!/bin/sh

sortedWord=`echo $1 | grep -o . | sort |tr -d "\n"`;
echo $sortedWord;
```